# How to use a variable defined outside of a select statement within a select statement

Tags: python, sql, pandas, postgresql, select

I want to use a select statement to isolate the first 525,600 rows from a data set which is pretty easy using the LIMIT statement, however I would like to do it for 58 separate tables. I have a list of my table names and am trying to define a function to iterate through all tables, however the variable name I have defined in the function is not recognized within the sql statement. Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import psycopg2

mylist = ['egauge13830','egauge13836','egauge13974','egauge14018','egauge14795','egauge15601',
          'egauge15623','egauge16133','egauge16608','egauge16616','egauge17073','egauge17311',
          'egauge18158','egauge18350','egauge18544','egauge19696','egauge19810','egauge19821',
          'egauge20358','egauge20407','egauge20670','egauge20925','egauge21932','egauge22084',
          'egauge22271','egauge22785','egauge23534','egauge24121','egauge24318','egauge2474',
          'egauge26086','egauge26944','egauge27467','egauge28351','egauge28489','egauge2850',
          'egauge2852','egauge28684','egauge30039','egauge30378','egauge3166','egauge3167',
          'egauge3171','egauge32290','egauge32507','egauge33764','egauge3608','egauge3611',
          'egauge4183','egauge5198','egauge6437','egauge7692','egauge7729','egauge7731',
          'egauge8253','egauge8617','egauge8816','egauge9102']

def first_chunk(egauge):
    engine = create_engine('postgresql://postgres:postgres@stargate/profiles')
    start_time_stmnt = """
    SELECT *
    FROM egauge
    LIMIT 525600
    """
    first = pd.read_sql_query(start_time_stmnt, engine)

def iterthro(data):
    for x in data:
        first_chunk(x)

iterthro(mylist)
```

The error I receive tells me that the relation "egauge" does not exist. Btw, I'm aware this code is pretty useless as it does nothing with the selected rows, but I plan to do more with this and would like to figure out this problem before I move forward. I've tried simple things like different combinations of quotations, and I'm not sure if I'm making a simple syntax mistake or if my logic is totally flawed. Thanks for any and all help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Here, egauge is a variable. So you can use `"{}".format(x)` to use the variable in string. I hope it helps!

```py
def first_chunk(egauge):
    engine = create_engine('postgresql://postgres:postgres@stargate/profiles')
    start_time_stmnt = """
    SELECT *
    FROM {}
    LIMIT 525600
    """.format(egauge)
    first = pd.read_sql_query(start_time_stmnt, engine)
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work? I don't have an example to test it on, but I think you need to separate your syntax from your variables better.

```
def first_chunk(egauge):
    engine = create_engine('postgresql://postgres:postgres@stargate/profiles')
    start_time_stmnt = " SELECT * " \
                       " FROM " + egauge + \
                       " LIMIT 525600 "
    first = pd.read_sql_query(sql=start_time_stmnt, con=engine, params=())
```

Comment: Yeah that works well, thank you! I really appreciate your quick response btw